# Prove: Content on a Ring is continuous from below $\Rightarrow$ continuous from above

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mathcal R$ be a ring on a set $X$ and $\mu: \mathcal R \to [0, \infty]$ a content. I have to show the following$$ \mu \textrm{ is continuous from below} \Rightarrow \mu \textrm{ is continuous from above}$$

I know that the definitions for "continuous from above/below" but i don't really know how to approach this prove.
Any tipps or ideas? Thanks in advance!